# Meteor: How to publish a meteoric app to the appstore?

Tags: android, meteor, app-store, ionic-framework, meteoric

Im quite new to meteor and meteoric and ionic... Well I built an app, it is fully functional and working very well on my Amazon EC2 instance and I can access it from any browser, that's ok, now I want to publish the app to the appstore or google play, but I can't find any documentation nor guided about how to publish apps made with meteoric. So I tried to research how to publish with ionic, however the guides are unfamiliar for me, since they use something called cordoba, and other stuff Im not familiar with. So I want to know if the ionic guides apply to meteoric (regarding app publishing) or ir the process is different. Would be great if someone provide some steps I can follow to publish the app. Thanks

Comment: I am also curious about ways to sell Meteor apps to large user bases.  But, unfortunately, questions about finding external docs or tutorials are off-topic on Stack Overflow.   Also, this question ends up being a question about an app store's commercial procedures, not a programming question.

Comment: Are you asking how to add platforms? or you have built for a specific platform and want to know the publishing process? Info about adding platforms here: http://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-mobile-development-meteor/ (uses cordova, built into meteor)

Comment: @SsouLlesS: Just asking if this worked out for you? For me it didn't, since the SCSS problem of Meteoric the app has a bad design on first run. I already posted an own SO question and then saw this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no expierence in submitting to the App Store but this is the way you would do it https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-iOS-app-to-App-Store